# How can a language model keep track of the provenance of the main knowledge/sources used to generate a given output?

Tags: natural-language-processing, language-model, chatgpt

One of the main criticisms against the use of ChatGPT on Stack Exchange is that it doesn't attribute the main knowledge/sources used to generate a given output. How can a language model keep track of the provenance of the main knowledge/sources used to generate a given output?

Answer (score 5):

Reddit user [skyebreak](https://www.reddit.com/user/skyebreak) [pointed](https://redd.it/znl8f8) me to a relevant paper on that topic:

Gao, Luyu, Zhuyun Dai, Panupong Pasupat, Anthony Chen, Arun Tejasvi Chaganty, Yicheng Fan, Vincent Y. Zhao et al. "[Attributed text generation via post-hoc research and revision.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.08037)" arXiv preprint arXiv:2210.08726 (2022).

> Large language models (LLMs) have shown impressive results across a variety of tasks while requiring little or no direct supervision. Further, there is mounting evidence that LLMs may have potential in information-seeking scenarios. We believe the ability of an LLM to attribute the text that it generates is likely to be crucial for both system developers and users in this setting. We propose and study Attributed QA as a key first step in the development of attributed LLMs. We develop a reproducable evaluation framework for the task, using human annotations as a gold standard and a correlated automatic metric that we show is suitable for development settings. We describe and benchmark a broad set of architectures for the task. Our contributions give some concrete answers to two key questions (How to measure attribution?, and How well do current state-of-the-art methods perform on attribution?), and **give some hints as to how to address a third key question (How to build LLMs with attribution?)**.